# Testing Twilio authy verify function

Tags: twilio, authy

Currently i am working with Sails and Authy.js API to authenticate new users using authy.verify function. Most of my code is in the callback to create new users.

I am in process of write tests to test my endpoints. What would be the best way to mock authy.verify function so that i can test my code in the callback function ?

I have tried using sinon and testdouble but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried with sinon or testdouble? I'm sure one or the other should be able to help you.

Comment: Actually, I see [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541969/sinon-how-to-stub-authentication-library-authy-twilio) got a better answer, so I'd carry on down that route.